# eZpublish 5 yml-config - link to different siteacces with map\url

Tags: symfony, yaml, config, ezpublish

I had 2 sites in one ezpublish 4.7 installation and updated now to 5.1.

My problem is that i had this configuration:

```
MatchOrder=host_uri
HostUriMatchMapItems[]=siteone.de;en;siteone_en
HostUriMatchMapItems[]=siteone.de;;siteone_de

HostUriMatchMapItems[]=sitetwo.de;en;sitetwo_en
HostUriMatchMapItems[]=sitetwo.de;;sitetwo_de
```

and i don't know how to write this in the new yaml-config file(ezpublish.yml)

I want to get to the english site-access **siteone_en** with the url **www.siteone.de/en**
and to the english site-access **sitetwo_en** with the url **www.sitetwo.de/en**.

Actually my file looks like this:

```
    match: 
      URIElement: 1          
      Map\URI:
            en: siteone_en
            site_admin: site_admin
      Map\Host:
            siteone.de: siteone_de
            sitetwo.de: sitetwo_de
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all available SiteAccess matchers in [official documentation](https://confluence.ez.no/display/EZP52/Siteaccess+Matching#SiteaccessMatching-Availablematchers). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: what about [Compound siteaccess matcher](https://confluence.ez.no/display/EZP52/Siteaccess+Matching#SiteaccessMatching-Availablematchers), you can build custom queries with it